# Graph related confusion

Tags: soft-question

I was working with some graph questions and came up with two variants of equations of the graph.

[image]

Plotting those two equations give $2$ graphs which are almost same looking and nearly to overlap each other, is there any reason why that happens? I may sound a bit dumb here.

Comment: Who says they're the "same" plot?  Ummm... What's your question?

Comment: There has to be some relation between the two eq I mean why they plot the same looking graphs

Comment: I don’t think they look *the same*. The red one has 4 components, while the blue one has two...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similarity is from inverse relations. The equation degrees 2,4 are different, latter one is a rectangular hyperbola.

Similar is not same.